# Spark vs Hive Hourly Directory Partitioning

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Spark, by default, does hourly directory partitioning like:

```
basepath/timestamp=YYYY-MM-dd HH%3Amm%3Ass/data
```

Hive does

```
basepath/year=YYYY/month=MM/day=dd/hour=HH/data
```

Is there a reason to use one vs the other?

Will the Spark style cause problems with using Hive or the Hive style cause problems with using Spark?

Comment: `timestamp=YYYY-MM-dd HH%3Amm%3Ass` will create 365*24*60*60 = 31536000 per year directories (which is lot of metadata to manage for namenode) vs `year=YYYY/month=MM/day=dd/hour=HH` will create 8640 directories.

Comment: Well, I was planning on truncating timestamp values to the hour so that the minute and second portions of the former would always be zero, but they would be included so that the timestamp value would be a normal rfc 3339 date+time string that Spark will automatically parse as a timestamp.